# Bind socket, and recvfrom in separated functions

Tags: php, laravel, sockets

I'm trying to receive UDP data from a game. And update it on the page constantly. Using JSON to retrieve the data from a function.

Is it possible to separate socket_create/socket_bind from socket_recvfrom?

(I've cut some unnecessary code out of it)

```
private $socket;

public function socketConnect($port)
{

    $ip = '0.0.0.0'; // local IP
    $port = 20777; // port to listen

    $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    socket_bind($this->socket, $ip, $port) or die("Could not connect");

   return view('telemetry');
}

public function getData()
{
   while (socket_recvfrom($this->socket, $buf, $bytes, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port)) {
      // do something
      return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

I've tried setting $this->socket to keep the data but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, no. Sockets created with the socket_* methods are not persistent, since they are low level sockets. And here your two functions are executed in two different page calls that are independent from each other (this is how PHP works).

Furthermore, what you are trying to do right now is a socket server (binding a socket is for server purposes usually), and socket servers need to be open continually to receive data. I would advise you to try to do a CLI program (that can still be done in PHP) and use the [socket_recvfrom](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.socket-recvfrom.php) and [socket_sendto](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.socket-sendto.php) methods to get and send your data (after doing your bind), and then store the received data in a database or in a file, to then have your website read from that to send it to your browser. [Here is a howto that shows how to create a simple UDP server in PHP](https://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-php/).

Comment: Alright thanks! My goal eventually is so people on my website can enable sending data from their game to the website, and have a live page with that data. To know which connection belongs to the players game, I was thinking of assigning them a random port. Now: how would I run the CLI program, for example when a user clicks "start" button on the website? Or should I have a program running 24/7 which detects the "start" and then make it execute data retrieval in a loop?

Comment: You would have to have the program run 24/7, the game sending data to your program whenever it needs, your program saving that data into a database (for example) and then your website retrieving said data from the database when people refresh the web page.